# pyImporterror running subfolder python scripts from the parent folder

Tags: python

I am trying to run from the `directory` folder:
`$ python subdirectoryTwo/file.py` command (Python 2.7).

Folders structure:

```
-directory  

    -subdirectoryOne  
        __init.py__
        config.py
    -subdirectoryTwo  
        __init.py__  
        file.py
```

My `file.py` has:
`from subdirectoryOne.config import config`

However I am getting an error:

> file.pyImportError: No module named subdirectoryOne.config`

(I guess it still looks in the `directory` folder)

Comment: probably helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions (not the optimum one) is to set `PYTHONPATH` to your `directory`:
`$ export PYTHONPATH='/absolute/path/to/directory'`

Answer (score 0):

There few thins you need to change.

(public)landpacks-MacBook-Pro:qx frank$ tree

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── config.py
│   └── config.pyc
└── b
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

Create a `__init__.py` with with your `subdirectoryOne` and `subdirectoryTwo` like here I used `a` and `b`. and then add few codes at the begin of your `file.py`. And I name it as `test.py` here. the code is:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from project.a.config import myconf


print(myconf)
```

You can see I import it by `project.a.config` instead of `a.config`. because you run your code under the project.

**UPDATE**

My `a/config.py` just simple with:

```
(public)landpacks-MacBook-Pro:qx frank$ cat a/config.py
myconf='127.0.0.1'
```